# How to access the values left, top individually in pywinauto.controls.hwndrapper.rectangle?

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

On pywinauto.rectangle() i get the position on screen of the window that I set_focus(), and on client_rect() I get the size of that window.

I want to grab the left and top of the window position on screen and the width and height of the window size.

I manage to get the width and height with a different function:
w=pywinauto.win32structures.RECT.width(client_rect)
h=pywinauto.win32structures.RECT.height(client_rect)

but I cant access the left and top.

```py
app = controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper(title)
rect = app.rectangle()
# print out
rect (L1293, T6, R1851, B1026)
rect type <class 'pywinauto.win32structures.RECT'>


app = controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper(title)
client_rect = app.client_rect()
# print out
client_rect (L0, T0, R558, B1020)
client_rect type <class 'pywinauto.win32structures.RECT'>


# I cant access like this either:
values = []
app = controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper(title)
rect = app.rect()
values.append(rect)
# print out
values [<RECT L1293, T6, R1851, B1026>]
values type <class 'list'>

# I try this too:
x = values[0]
# prints out:
x (L1293, T6, R1851, B1026)

x = values[1]
# prints out
x = values[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Which version of pywinauto is used? Did you try `dir(client_rect)`?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov i'm using version 0.6.7, with dir(client_rect) I can see the 'left' and 'top' as properties, but how I can use this properties to get the values out of them, thanks.

Comment: Iterating by index is supported for `POINT` object only. So you have to use attribute names for all four numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just simple attributes of the `client_rect` object:

```
print(client_rect.left, client_rect.top, client_rect.right, client_rect.bottom)
```

Also there is additional method to get central point of the rect:

```
print(client_rect.mid_point())
```

Height and width are also methods:

```
print(client_rect.width())
print(client_rect.height())
```

Comment: Thanks, it's more simpler than I thought, I was using pyautoit win_get_pos() and used index, needed to change because I can't get it working on Nuitka.